# White space in footer in scroll down and up in Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, safari, cross-browser, whitespace, space

I have a WordPress website and when I am trying to open that website into Safari browser and scroll up and down then there is white space is showing in the footer.
Website URL - https://thecoju.com/
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have checked but nothing found, only issue with JetPop wordpress Plugin

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved, that was due to cross-browser and CSS was not working